# Smarty call a static class method

Tags: php, smarty

I want to call a php method in my smarty template.

I have the class

```
class TestClass
{
    public static myMth($vars) {
        var_dump($vars);
    }
}
```

In my template i put:

```
{TestClass::myMth($someVar)}
```

That doesn't work. I have the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'myMth' (T_STRING), expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE)

Is there something wrong in my code ?

Comment: Have you assigned `myMyth` in the smarty engine? As in `$objSmarty->assign("common", "objectname"); ` and then use in smarty as `{$common->function_name($arg1,$arg2)} ` - via http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=65907&sid=8d4d448b79ec7c15c6933b2b3dc4a47b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact it works without a problem (Smarty 3.1.19):

In PHP:

```
$data['elements'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
$smarty->assign('someVar',$data);

class TestClass
{
    public static function myMth($vars) { // added function word here - you missed it in question
        var_dump($vars);

        echo "<br />test test test<br />";
    }
}
```

In Smarty:

```
{TestClass::myMth($someVar)}
```

Output:

```
array(1) { ["elements"]=> array(11) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(5) [5]=> int(6) [6]=> int(7) [7]=> int(8) [8]=> int(9) [9]=> int(10) [10]=> int(11) } }
test test test
```

However I don't think it's the best way of using Smarty.

You should rather use:

```
$smarty->assign('result', TestClass::myMth($data));
```

Why? It's quite simple. Smarty is Template engine and you should only display data here. You should not launch classes/method and so on. What if `myMyth` function name will change or arguments will change? You will need to change your Smarty template files. Better is to assign to Smarty only output of this method.

However if you still want to do that you can also look at [Static classes](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.static.classes.tpl) section at Smarty website.

Comment: I need to export datas to CSV but i can't save datas somewhere. Idea is to call a php class who export datas to CSV !  The problem was the missing 'function' word.

Comment: @Sancho If you just want to call it and save it on hard drive, why don't you do it in your PHP code? You should do it before displaying Smarty template in PHP and then display Smarty template

Comment: The idea was to generate the csv on the user demand without save datas. Now i think it's not possible that way. For the moment i have no ideas to do that. I want to save the error report from an import form (i can't get errors twice) only when an user click on a link.

Comment: @Sancho, so why don't you create link/button and when user clicks it, you reload the page, generate CSV and save the error_report?

Comment: The problem is where can i save datas i need to generate the file ? It's some 'temp' datas. What's the better way to save them ? Session ? Cookie ?